# How to configure the CORS on the Vite server to remove the CORS error when loading images

Tags: vue.js, canvas, cors, vite, image-loading

I have a Vite/Vue 3 application where I get an error like this when loading images.

> Access to image at 'https://website.com/image-url.jpg' from origin 'https://my-web-app-url.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The function that loads images looks like this:

```
const imageLoader = (image: HTMLImageElement, url: string): Promise<HTMLImageElement> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = () => resolve(image);
    image.onerror = () => reject(image);
  });
};
```

I need to load an image in order to create a canvas with the loaded image, this function looks like this:

```
const createCanvas = async (url: string): Promise<CanvasObject | null> => {
  const image = new Image();
  const loaded = await imageLoader(image, url);
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.setAttribute("visibility", "hidden");
  canvas.width = loaded.width;
  canvas.height = loaded.height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  if (ctx) {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    return { ctx, width: image.width, height: image.height };
  } else {
    console.error("context not found");
    return null;
  }
};
```

What i've already try:

1. Set image cross origin like this:

> **image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"**

2. Passing dummy query params to url like this (which disables image caching, as I understand it):

> **image.src = url + "?" + new Date().getTime()**

3. Enable cors and set cors origin to "*" in vite.config:

> ```
>   server: {
>     cors: { origin: "*" },
>   }
> ```

4. Add proxy rules to vite.config:

> ```
>   server: {
>     proxy: {
>       "/": {
>         target: "https://image-aware-background.vercel.app",
>         changeOrigin: true,
>         secure: false,
>         rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\//, ""),
>       },
>     },
>   }
> ```

But none of these methods helped me to solve the CORS error.

I see the access-control-allow-origin header in the [original application request](https://i.ibb.co/92fyqGf/2022-11-06-130205.png), but it is not in the [image download request](https://i.ibb.co/djLbLpW/2022-11-06-130235.png).

How to reproduce issue:

1. go to https://image-aware-background.vercel.app/
2. open dev console
3. paste any image [link](https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/974/565/254/windows-11-windows-10-minimalism-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg) (just press ctrl+v on the page)
4. сheck the error in the console

Comment: dude cors is always on the server side. you should do nothing on the client side. If you have no access to the server side or they have no idea about it, you can use backdoor-cors to proxy requests and handle the situation. But CORS IS ALWAYS SERVER SIDE.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-backdoor

Comment: I already enable cors on server side with vite config file. But image load request doesn't have cors header. Dude, that's the point

Comment: your image is on  'https://website.com/image-url.jpg' and your vue project is on 'https://my-web-app-url.com', right? If so, server is the first and client is second and trust me, the problem is on the server.

Comment: Yes, but my client app also has a server part, in which you can set a cors origin header with value "*", which allows to use any resource from other servers, without checking if the origin request matches. And my problem is that the image retrieval request does not contain allow cross origin header. With great respect, but if you can't help, you should have just not tried to help me. After all, I could be wrong too.

Comment: you have a webpack (or vite) server which serves your client code. But the point is this part cannot resolve your issue. You have to config the other side (the server which serves the image) to resolve it. or use a proxy server to add the response headers.

Comment: Does your problem solved?

Comment: No, I'm still looking for a solution, but I'll try not to create a new img tag, but use the existing img tag to create the canvas.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I described the solution in my answer. Thank you for suggesting the solution with the proxy server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was able to figure it out after all, thanks to [Ali Bahrami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4546568/ali-bahrami).

If you need to download an image from a server that has a strictly configured CORS, you need to use a proxy server, which will return the data to you with the required headers.

I used https://allorigins.win/. You need to put the address of the proxy server at the beginning of your url.

```
https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=https://example.org/
```

So, my image loader function started looking like this:

```
export const imageLoader = (image: HTMLImageElement, url: string): Promise<HTMLImageElement> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    image.src = "https://api.allorigins.win/raw?url=" + url;
    image.onload = () => resolve(image);
    image.onerror = () => reject(image);
  });
};
```